# iOS Error: Cannot convert value of type 'UserModel' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am trying to save user information in `FireBaseFirestore`, the function I am using is from the `Firestore` documentation. I Am getting that error but the app is running fine and the data is saved correctly.

[image]

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7HaG.png that's the link for the error screensot

Comment: The error is pretty clear: The method you call expects an argument of one type, but you pass a variable of another type.

Comment: `setData` method is expecting an object of type `[String: Any]` and you are passing Custom class object.  And to solve this error you need to convert your custom object to `[String: Any]` type.

Comment: What does the documentation say? Firebase has a full section on custom objects and another large section on how to do all the basic functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to convert your `UserModel` to `[String : Any]` type in order to save it on firebase. Try this:

```
func convertUserModelToDictionary(user: UserModel) -> [String : Any] {

    let userData = [
        "name" : user.name,      // change these according to you model
        "email": user.email,
        "user_id": user.userId
    ]
    
    return userData
}
```

You can use this function as:

```
do {
    let userData = convertUserModelToDictionary(user: userInfo)
    try db.collection("usersInformations").document(userInfo.id).setData(from: userData)
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: On The Firebase Documentation, This is the recommended way, and it's working, the data is saved despite the error given by Xcode. I just want to know why it's giving this error even though the code is working fine.

Comment: @HassanH'Sheaib it was giving error because the firebase's 'setData' method accept '[String : Any]' type if you look at its documentation, not the model. So, I am providing you the possible solution for this error.